# nested recycler view with footer in both child and parent recycler view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, footer

I am new to android and this is my first question on stack overflow I am trying to implement recycler view with footer. I have a nested recycler view, and want to implement footer in child recycler view and parent recycler view.
I need this implementation with "Kotlin"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HGAe.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have a `RecyclerView`, in which, the first element, must always be some placeholder.

In such a case, you can proceed as follows:

1. Prepare your data classes and layouts. I've made abstract class

`

```
abstract class YourImaginedDataClassInterface(open val id: Int)
```

`

And it's childs

```
data class YourImaginedClass(
    override val id: Int,
    val somethingElse: Any?
): YourImaginedDataClassInterface(id)

data class YourPlaceHolderClass(
    override val id: Int
): YourImaginedDataClassInterface(id) {
    companion object {
        const val TITLE_ID = -1
        val PLACEHOLDER_TEMPLATE_OBJECT = YourPlaceHolderClass(TITLE_ID)
    }
}
```

2. Create standart RecyclerView.Adapter class
3. Override `getItemViewType` to detect if the object is your placeholder class

`

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (holder is YourViewHolder) {
        //bind your inner recyclerView here
    }
}
```

`

4. In `onCreateViewHolder` - check viewType and inflate correct layout

`

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): 
RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    return when (viewType) {
        PLACEHOLDER -> PlaceholderViewHolder(
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.placeholder, parent, false)
        )
        ELEMENT -> YourViewHolder(
            inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.item_layout, parent, false
            )
        )
        else -> throw RuntimeException("Unexpected viewType")
    }
}
```

`

5. In onBindViewHolder - bind your item layouts if expected

`

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (holder is YourViewHolder) {
        //bind your inner recyclerView here
    }
}
```

`

6. Create one more adapter, initialize nested recyclerView in onBindViewHolder if you want nested RecyclerView

[Full example](https://gist.github.com/NarutoBratishka/005fc3337392589151dd6a680da6e98e)

P.S. Sorry for code fields. It makes me buttheart